# What is Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr's role in Tears of the Sun?

Tags: tears-of-the-sun

Two of the cast members are listed as Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr. as Bujo, and Sammi Rotibi as Arthur Azuka.
[image]

However, there isn't anyone called Bujo in the movie. Also, when you look at *Tears of the Sun*'s characters photo, you can see that Arthur Azuka looks like both Sammi Rotibi and Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr.
[image]

I'm confused. If Arthur Azuka is played by Sammi Rotibi, then why does the photo of him look like Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr.? In which scene of the film did Habimana Jr. appear?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Your question was quite hard to understand, so I've done my best to edit it into something I can make sense of. If you feel like I've misrepresented what you're trying to ask, feel free to make further edits to try and clarify further.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post images to illustrate your point.

Comment: IMDB can have contributions made by those other than the producer or crew involved on the project. The same picture, but zoomed in, is actually credited to Sammi Rotibi, and there are other pictures which are also credited to this actor in scenes from this film. This probably confirms that the Fabrice credit is a mistake. Since there are no pictures of Fabrice, and he seems quite inactive, it is likely never to be confirmed if he ever looked anything remotely like Sammi, or wore the same costume (highly unlikely), so this is unverifiable.

Comment: Movies get lots of edits, whatever part the Bujo character had probably got cut, but would have been left in the Call Sheet if his scenes were filmed with him in. That kind of production information would have been used to build the IMDB cast & crew list, without being verified, and they would not be responsible for crediting Fabrice with that picture - basically anyone (without any connection to the project) could have done that for the actor.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot to go on here, other than it looks like Fabrice's credited picture is a mistake:

Consider this - the pictures on the left are all of Sammi, credited as such, on the right is the only known picture credited to Fabrice. Look at the costume - only one character would be assigned that, and it is Sammi. (Sammi's character is important enough to get an on set interview for the 'Making Of' video)

[image]

As for Fabrice as Bujo, the cast & crew list is usually made up from documents such as Call Sheets (for example) that list talent required for filming (for a particular scene, or day), amongst other production information.

It is entirely possible that Fabrice played a character called Bujo that was subsequently cut out in the edit, but left in the cast list by virtue of having been cast, costumed, hair and make up done, and even filmed but ultimately not seen in the final cut.

This has happened before.

Note also that numerous characters might be referred to or are shown doing things that might have had names assigned (in the Call Sheet) but are not referred to on screen (or might have been, but again might have been edited out for various reasons) - Bujo could have been any of them.

Ultimately, due to the time passed and the inactivity of the Fabrice actor, it is likely that we will never know who Bujo was or even what Fabrice looked like in the movie.

So as OP asks:

> *If Arthur Azuka is played by Sammi Rotibi, then why does the photo of him look like Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr.?*

The Sammi Rotibi credit is correct, the Fabrice photo credit looks like a mistake.

Note the difference between the photos that cast are credited with on the movie project, and the photo that the individual actor is credited with on their own page - the two have no relation to each other.

Literally anyone could have credited Fabrice with that picture, whilst normally the movie entry would have been entered by a staffer from the production company.

When a name is entered (cast list for example), there is an opportunity for it to be linked up with an existing entry (or create a new one), so whilst the production company staffer entering the movie details would have control over listing who worked on the movie, they would not have control over what picture an actor (or someone else) has picked for his own profile, that would only show up later when the page is updated (as the options are usually drop down text with no pictures shown).

Note, sites like IMDB are a bit like Wikipedia - *anyone can contribute and edit and delete* items. Sometimes there is verification required and there is some moderation but **it is open to mistakes and abuse**.

> *In which scene of the film did Habimana Jr. appear?*

At this stage, it is unverifiable if he was ever seen in the theatrical release.

Answer (score 0):

The photos are correct and they are two different people.

Fabrice Yahve Habimana Jr. is an actor, known for Tears of the Sun (2003) and Voices of Africa (2004).

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1334158/bio

Sammi Rotibi is an actor, known for Tears of the Sun (2003), Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (2016) and Lord of War (2005).

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0745353/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what @Farshid is asking. From the OP, both actors are credited. What is asked is about the inconsistency of the name and scenes and looks. I think you miss the target here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Aside from missing the point, the picture used for Fabrice is also used for Sammi, the difference being that there are more pictures out there that credit Sammi in that same costume and look than there is Fabrice (precisely one), making the latter credit look more like a mistake.